# Custom Icons Displayed Incorrectly in URL Files

Tags: windows-10, icons, url

On Windows 10, I am saving all browser bookmarks as local URL files where I can use the built-in syntax below to pick the identifying icon from ICO files stored on the same drive.

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=http://www.microsoft.com
IconFile=D:\bookmarks\icons\microsoft.ico
IconIndex=0
```

The problem is that only about 20% of URL files display the correctly chosen icon, while the rest display a system icon (earth globe). Clearing the cache and restarting did not resolve the issue. However, when I rename the local ICO file name by adding "1" to the end and make the corresponding change in the URL file, the icon is displayed correctly. For usability reasons, I need to use the correct name of each ICO file, i.e. without "1", and I cannot identify the reason for the problem.

Comment: +1 for clearly stating the issue on this puzzler. Your testing has shown that since you're storing the icons separately, the issue is *not* due to clearing the browser cache, but I don't know what would cause it.

Comment: Are the icons that are not displaying correctly on a separate drive than the ones that are displaying correctly?

Comment: I tried unsuccessfully to reproduce this problem - could you share with us one such icon? Can you change the icon to the right one with right-click, Properties and Change Icon?

Comment: The icons are all on the same drive as the URL files, albeit in different folders. They are icons with 48x48 and 32x32 images. The manual change via File Property works for files that do not present a problem, in the others the terrestrial globe icon cannot be changed.